# Is there a python equivalent of ruby's "Pathname" module?

Tags: python, ruby

Ruby has this really handy module called [Pathname](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Pathname.html).

Is there a python equivalent to it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which path module or class do Python folks use instead of os.path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252639/which-path-module-or-class-do-python-folks-use-instead-of-os-path)

Comment: Not exactly the same...but similar info.  I ended up writing my own Pathname like OO wrapper: http://github.com/docwhat/homedir/blob/master/lib/homedir/pathname.py

Answer (score 5):

`pathlib` is the answer to all your python path woes.

Example functionality:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path.cwd()

with (p/'somefile.txt').open() as f:
    f.read()

p.is_dir()
```

Answer (score 2):

That looks a lot like [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html).

Comment: Same functionality, but not not object oriented.

Comment: The ruby lib is object oriented, so I assumed that was what he was looking for, because I didn't think someone would need to ask if python had functionality for path manipulation.  It just seemed too obvious.

Comment: Lots of people have made OO-style interfaces to pathname manipulation. No-one has come up with one that everyone's happy to put in the stdlib though. See [PEP 355](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0355/)

Comment: mikirobi is right... Ruby has two ways to manipulate path objects.  One is like the `os.path` stuff, the one I want is OO based.